# How do I pass a post through two pages?

Tags: php, tcpdf

In TCPDF I'm unable to put any database queries on the page that generates the PDF. To get around this I decided to try and separate the actions out, so the first action is to save some details to the database. The second action is to go to the PDF generator to finally make the PDF. So the order of pages would be:

1- User fills in form -> 2- Database gets essential post details -> 3- TCPDF generates PDF

Is there a way to easily pass my $_POST through the second and third pages? (I've used hidden input fields to store data before but I've got hundreds and it seems highly impractical this time)

Thanks

Comment: Why not create the PDF when also the data gets inserted. That way you only need one `$_POST` ?

Comment: TCPDF needs the action page to generate the PDF, it doesn't really let you do anything else on that page (at least I think)

Comment: I know but you can generate the PDF > save it on the server and also post details the database in the same POST.

Comment: The queries don't run on the page where it processes the post data to the PDF. I've put the queries on other pages and they work, just not when there's TCPDF involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make ajax POST request to the database with the fields you have filled.
And then redirect your page to the pdf generation.

Comment: That works nicely, I'm sending ajax to do the database stuff and php to create the PDF. Thanks!!

Comment: @ERushforth Welcome :)

Answer (score 2):

Creating multiple hidden fields on each page to store your initial `$_POST` data is not really realistic.

You could use `$_SESSION` instead of `$_POST`. By using sessions your data will be stored between the pages. So after the first post of your form, save all your data in a session.

Example:

`$_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['name'];`

When generating your PDF you would use the variable `$_SESSION['name']`.

Dont forget to unset sessions after using them, example: `unset($_SESSION['name']);`

PS: If you feel like it's too much work to add all fields, just do the following:

`$_SESSION['form'] = $_POST;`

You could access all form elements in the generator like this:

`$_SESSION['form']['nameOfYourField'];`

More information: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php

Comment: If he renamed every `$_POST` to `$_SESSION` which is basically what you're saying it will work? No! Please give some more information then just saying `$_SESSION` instead of `$_POST`

Comment: @Daan Updated the answer.

Comment: Unfortunately that would have still taken a lot of time to replace all the variables, I ended up using ajax to do the database stuff and the form action to do the pdf stuff. Thanks though.

Comment: Well i'm glad your problem is solved, but to remind you, this was your actual question: `Is there a way to easily pass my $_POST through the second and third pages?` An ajax call should not be the answer to your question, might confuse others..

Comment: I didn't have the time to be changing loads of content which is why I said the word "easily"